# 'Failed to apply network settings

Tags: network-manager

When I restart my computer I found a strange error related to blue-tooth. Error is :

```
Failed to apply network settings
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.PermissionsInvalid: The permission of the setuid helper is not correct You might not be able to connect to the Bluetooth network via this machine.
```

My system is dual boot. One OS is ubuntu 12.04 and another is windows 7. When I used to shutdown my system from ubuntu I am getting ubuntu login screen. Also I am unable to see the another drives of hard disk in ubuntu. Also If I insert the pendrive I have to mount it using command line. otherwise pendrive is not visible. Also wi-fi is not working.  Please help me out

Comment: If you have any doubt about how to ask questions read the FAQ(http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: Hello jaspreet, you should slip your question in to several pieces and post them separably, we can help you better when you do so. Ask Ubuntu works better if add more information to your questions, ie: *Wifi does not work* will be very hard to answer without any further information. Please edit your question(s) to provide any information necessary so we can help you out better.

Comment: @BrunoPereira What type information do you want to know? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

These problems seem to be caused by the dbus helper program having the incorrect permissions: it should have the setuid bit set but it doesn't. To fix this use this command and restart:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

To read more about this: http://f7t.fr/blog/?p=165